# Adding topology dataset to mxd using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers, topology

I have a script that identifies certain layers from a folder containing several geodatabases.  Part of the scripts purposes, or intended purpose is to have it add a topology dataset to the dataframe. I have tried both of these methods below with no success.  It's as if the topology cannot be treated as a layer and therefore cannot be added.

Is there a workaround to allow for topology data to be added to the map?

```
 elif name == "Topo_" + str(fileNameFull) + "_Topology":
        tempTopoPath = os.path.join(tempData,str(fileNameFull) + "_topoTemp")
        topologyPath = os.path.join(r'N:\29000s\29910\GIS\GI02\QC_Processing',fileNameFull,"FW_" + str(fileNameFull) + "_" + str(gdbDate) + ".gdb","Layers",str(name))
        topoLayer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(topologyPath, tempTopoPath)
        topologyLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(tempTopoPath)
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetGroupLayer, topologyLayer, "TOP")
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Here is another method I tried.

```
elif name == "Topo_" + str(fileNameFull) + "_Topology":
        topologyPath = os.path.join(r'N:\29000s\29910\GIS\GI02\QC_Processing',fileNameFull,"FW_" + str(fileNameFull) + "_" + str(gdbDate) + ".gdb","Layers",str(name))
        topologyLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(topologyPath)
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetGroupLayer, topologyLayer, "TOP")
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only types of layers you can add to an mxd with arcpy.mapping are *map* layers (layers in an mxd), and layer files (.lyr). A *feature* layer (in-memory layer) you create using the [Make Feature Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Make_Feature_Layer/00170000006p000000/) tool is not valid.

In addition, Make Feature Layer doesn't accept topologies as input (a topology is a dataset, not a feature class).

You can export a topology to a .lyr file by right-clicking it in the Catalog window, but not using the [Save To Layer File](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Save_To_Layer_File/001700000070000000/) tool, so you won't be able to automate this with arcpy.

So if a .lyr file of the topology doesn't already exist and if your topology isn't already present as a layer in another mxd, you will need ArcObjects to add it to your mxd.